# Subscription entry in the database when payment is complete

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a problem in wordpress.
So at the end of a payment in woocommerce, I would like to make a query and insert in a table in the database the name of the user, the type of subscription and the days required.
How do you think I could do that?
So far, I've written this

```
function wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase( $order_id ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    $product_id = 193; // that's a specific product ID
    
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        if( $product_id == $item['product_id'] && $order->user_id ) {
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

            // Remove old role
            $user->remove_role( 'Author' ); 

            // Add new role
            $user->add_role( 'Subscriber' );
            $query = $wpdb->insert('wp_pms_member_subscriptions', array(
            'id' => 1,
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'subscribtion_plan_id' => 233,
            'status' => 'active'
          ));
        
          $wpdb->query($query);

        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't really do what I want and I would like to make a query in this table and insert the member directly in the subscription table
[image]

And the name of table is
`wp_pms_member_subscriptions`